# how to create a display with arrays

Tags: powershell

I want to create table where it offers the user some options like change the ip to static and dynamic and i have a hash table like this. I just wanted to know the other ways to create this table without having to spam the $box variable

```
$Box=@("г","="," ","¬","¦","-","L","¦","¦")

Write-Host $Box[0]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[3]
Write-Host $Box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Title "  "$box[2] $box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $box[8]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[7]
write-host $Box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2] $MenuItems[0] $box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $Box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$MenuItems[1]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $Box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$Box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $box[4]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$MenuItems[2]$Box[2]$box[2]"  "$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[2]$box[4]
Write-host $box[6]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[1]$box[5]

$UserInput = Read-Host "Please make a selection [1-3]"
switch($UserInput)
{
    1 {Set-DHCP}
    2 {Set-StaticIP}
    3 {exit}
    default {Main}
}
```

Comment: You could just write the characters, instead of storing them in the box variable.

Comment: I swear there was a similar question just a few days ago with a nice answer. Unfortunately I can't find it no matter how I try. Perhaps it was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can consolidate that code **a lot** by using .NET string formatting. For example, the first two lines would look like the following:

```
$Lines = @(); # Create an empty array
$Lines += ('{0}' + '{1}'*33 + '{2}') -f $Box[0], $box[1], $box[3]; # Format and add the first line
$Lines += ('{0}' + '{1}'*9 + '{2}  ' + '{1}'*10 + '{0}') -f $Box[4], $box[2], $Title; # Format and add the second line
...
...
...
Write-Host -Object ($Lines -join "`n"); # Write out all lines, joined by a line separator.
```